# PAM Python Unix authentication without root privilege

Tags: python, linux, pam

I have a python script with PAM authentication, executes and prints success if it is executed with root where as if I execute it with non root privilege I am getting the below error

python: pam_unix(system-auth:auth): authentication failure;

Is there any possibility that I can run it with non root privilege please help me out.

FYI -

I am using the python script from https://code.google.com/p/web2py/source/browse/gluon/contrib/pam.py

Thanks

Comment: As far as I know, you can only authorize the current user if you aren't  running the script root.  I'm curious to know the answer to this as well.  I use PAM for a Django app, and I can only log in as myself when debugging (local user is running the app, not root).  [does this question help?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746932/pam-authentication-problem)

Comment: I already tried by placing custom config file in pam.d directory and passing it to service of authenticate function but I see the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow me.
Enter following command in console.
    $su root
    $chmod 7777 ./script
    $chown root root ./script

later excute setuid(root), setgid(root) function in script file.