# how to authenticate my ubuntu account not root using python-pam?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pam

I installed python-pam in https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-pam/1.8.2
and I commended in ubuntu 14.04

```
python
import pam
p=pam.pam()
p.authenticate('myname','mypassword')
```

it work good when I input my root account info.
but when i input normal account info, it returns FALSE.

how to authenticate my ubuntu account not root using python-pam?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746932/pam-authentication-problem

Answer (score 0):

It won't work if you use their usual system (unix style) login credentials. The PAM library must read the shadow file which is only readable by root. However, if you use a PAM profile that authenticates with an alternate method, such as LDAP or a database, then it can work without needing root.